# My UIWebView is being called though I've not performed any segue

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, webview, segue

I have a `UIWebView` which when intercepts a particular URL makes a transition to a `UIViewController`.

When a button is clicked this `viewController` presents another `UIViewController` modally.

What's weird is that when a unwind segue is performed to the first `UIViewController`, it appears for a split second only to show the `webView` and I am fairly certain that this is the same `webView` as the first one as this `webView` "continues" from the URL it left previously and also all the variables initiated in the `webView` have the values they held prior to the segue.

```
func makeHTTPGetRequest(path: String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    if (NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as? [NSHTTPCookie] != nil) || ((NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as? [NSHTTPCookie])! != []){
        ToolBox.cookieJar = (NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as? [NSHTTPCookie])!
        //            ToolBox.maxIndex++
    }
    println(NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as? [NSHTTPCookie])
    var cookies = ToolBox.cookieJar
    var headers : NSDictionary = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(cookies)
    var storage : NSHTTPCookieStorage = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()
    for cookie in storage.cookies  as! [NSHTTPCookie]{
        storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = (headers as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies = true
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var bodyData = "frontend=android"
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let json:JSON = JSON(data: data)
        onCompletion(json,error)
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

I set debug points in all the suspicious places, just before the `viewController` moves to the `webView`, `task.resume()` is called.

The `webView` shows up now, but the code in the `viewController` class is getting executed.

I am trying to understand what might have been the reason this is happening for the past couple of hours with no luck. I am pretty sure that I am not calling the `webView` at all, in fact it is the initial view controller and no other class calls it, so the only possible reason is that the `webView` is getting called implicitly by some function I am using, but I am unable tot figure it out, I am reading docs for every function but I found nothing to solve this bug.

If someone knows the reason for the bug, please share it with me.

**EDIT:** One more thing I think is important to mention is that from the animation of the transition from the `viewController` to `webView` , it seems as if the `viewController` is unwinding to `webView`, which is odd since the segue from `webView` to `viewController` is a show segue.

**Update:** I commented all the code in my `viewWillAppear()` and `viewDidAppear()` and ran the app. The webView popped up just after `viewDidAppear()` function got called the `viewWillAppear()` of webView is getting called.

**Update2:** Thanks for everyone who tried to solve this problem. The bug turned out to be a very stupid one.

```
@IBAction func unwindToList(segue : UIStoryboardSegue){
    if !segue.sourceViewController.isBeingDismissed() {
        segue.sourceViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I was dismissing the `souceViewController` which was the very reason it went back to the webView. Sorry for posting such stupid question